# derive from ReadOnlyObservableCollection Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

Assume that I have a collection of `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` type and I want to register to its event `CollectionChanged` which is protected...

I thought that it I can overcome in a simple way, so I've created my own class which derives from `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` and then I've subscribed for the event and invoked my own ones:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>
{
    public MyCollection(ObservableCollection<T> list) : base(list)
    {
        this.CollectionChanged += ThreadMessagesCollection_CollectionChanged;
        this.PropertyChanged += ThreadMessagesCollection_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void ThreadMessagesCollection_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }

    private void ThreadMessagesCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnCollectionChanged(sender, e);
    }

    public delegate void CollectionChagedDelegate(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e);

    protected event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler  OnCollectionChanged;
}
```

But, now the binding doesn't work. And no exceptions detected...

Any idea what I've done wrong, or how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a problem with your `event OnCollectionChanged`, because `OnCollectionChanged` is already a virtual method of `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`.

I suggest to try it like this:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>
{
  public MyCollection([NotNull] ObservableCollection<T> list) : base(list) {}
  protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
  {
    base.OnCollectionChanged(args);
    OnMyCollectionChanged(args);
  }
  public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler MyCollectionChanged;
  protected virtual void OnMyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler = MyCollectionChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
  }
}
```

You don't need to define your own delegate since there is alread a `NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler` declared.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I also found a way to do so - without inheritance, I simply cast my (ReadOnlyObservableCollection  as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged . Which gives me the ability of subscribing to the event :)